# select a single image in a row of images in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a JSON file where i have the details about a machine. I need to display these details along with the images in a row based on their size and once displayed i should be able to select one images from this list.

Appreciate your help in this. Thanks in Advance.
Sample JSON Data:

```
[{
    "large": [{
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "medium": [{
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "small": [{
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      },
      {
        "cpus": "",
        "memory": "",
        "name": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Here is the sample the way we need to display the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS0ec.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about you concern but... If you use AngularJS (as tagged), you could add images to your JSON this way:

```
{
    "large": [
                {
                    "cpus": "Test item",
                    "memory": "Test description",
                    "name": "Test name",
                    "images": [
                        {   "id": "1",
                            "url": "https://effortz.com/wp-content/uploads/dedicated-hosting-server.png" },
                        {   "id": "2",
                            "url": "https://1.cms.s81c.com/sites/default/files/2018-08-28/Systems-Servers-mainframe-360x360-min.jpg" }
                    ]
                }
             ]
}
```

..and then you could use them in code like:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.dataset">
        <div>{{item.cpus}}</div>
        <div>{{item.memory}}</div>
        <div>{{item.name}}</div>
        <div>
            <span ng-repeat="img in item.images"><img ng-src="{{img.url}}" ng-click="$ctrl.selectImage(img)"></img></span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Check [this](https://codepen.io/loenko/pen/rQGGWq?editors=1011) out!

Comment: And, of course, if you confused AngularJS with Angular 2+ (as you tagged the question with 'typescript'), some adjustments will be needed)) But you've got the direction, I believe)

Comment: Thanks @Fyodor. Sorry for the confusion.I am a new bee to Angular so got confused with Js and 2. I want to display all the images and data that i have in the json and should be able to select one image of all the available 9 images. I am trying to do this using a radio button for each image, so that i can select only 1 item at a time. but could not make it work.

Comment: I would recommend to make a short demo at https://stackblitz.com/ and put it here so that anyone could get the source code overview and suggest a solution